# Alimentar lista dá "Indice fora do intervalo"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, lista

No meu sistema, preciso retornar a quantidade de perguntas que o aluno errou em um determinado tema. Para conseguir isto, tentei criando uma classe que possui dois atributos: `Tema` e `QteErros` e instanciei ela no meu controlador.

```
public ActionResult errosPorTema(int idAluno)
{
   Aluno a = alunoModel.obterAluno(idAluno);
   List<Tema> temasalunoAtividadeModel.listarTemasPorAluno(idAluno);

   List<ErradaTema> listaErradasTema = new List<ErradaTema>();

   for (int i = 0; i < temas.Count; i++)
   {
      int idTema = temas[i].idTema;
      int qtdErros =      alunoAtividadeModel.listarPerguntasErradasPorTema2(a.idAluno, idTema);

      listaErradasTema[i].Tema = temas[i].Descricao;
      listaErradasTema[i].QtdErradas = qtdErros;
    }

    return View(listaErradasTema);
}
```

A classe `ErradaTema`:

```
public class ErradaTema
    {
        public string Tema { get; set; }
        public int QtdErradas { get; set; }

        public ErradaTema(string tema, int qtdErradas)
        {
            this.Tema = tema;
            this.QtdErradas = qtdErradas;
        }

        public ErradaTema()
        {

        }

    }
```

O problema está nas linhas `listaErradasTema[i].Tema = temas[i].Descricao;` e
 `listaErradasTema[i].QtdErradas = qtdErros;`.

Comment: Se você colocar o código ao invés de imagem e como é a classe `ErradaTema` eu posso melhorar a resposta e tentar ver se há algo mais errado.

Comment: Ok. Vou editar a pergunta com o código, e mostrar a classe  ErradaTema

Comment: [Edit] a pergunta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é que você não está adicionando um elemento na lista nova. Você não pode acessar o elemento sem criá-lo antes. nem precisa acessá-lo de fato:

```
public ActionResult errosPorTema(int idAluno) {
    Aluno a = alunoModel.obterAluno(idAluno);
    List<Tema> temas = alunoAtividadeModel.listarTemasPorAluno(idAluno);
    var listaErradasTema = new List<ErradaTema>();
    for (int i = 0; i < temas.Count; i++) {
        listaErradasTema.Add(new ErradaTema() {
            Tema = temas[i].Descricao,
            QtdeErradas = alunoAtividadeModel.listarPerguntasErradasPorTema2(a.idAluno, temas[i].idTema)
        });
    }
    return View(listaErradasTema);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/GetDataList.cs).

Veja mais em [Por que ocorre e como resolver um erro de "out of bounds" ou "out of range" ou algo de tipo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411417/101).

Já que a classe possui um construtor com as duas propriedades, poderia inicializar com ele. Mas [duvido que este construtor seja necessário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). O outro construtor certamente não é necessário. Eu simplificaria esta classe e deixaria só as propriedades. A não ser que ela vá crescer.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Bigown! era isto mesmo.

Comment: Eu fiz um acerto porque depois que editou é que deu para conferir melhor o código.

Comment: Vlw! me ajudou bastante!!!